# How do I add a collider to the Unity Scientist Character

Tags: collision-detection, mesh, unity-game-engine

i created a sample scene an placed the unity Scientist character into the scene. I create a sphere with a sphere collider and placed it above the character. When I play the scene, the ball falls through the character. I've tried to add a mesh collider to the character, but to no avail. How does one add collision detection to a unity character?

Comment: This question is rather broad for the nature of the site - consider researching some of the helpful resources already available to you, before bringing your question to Stack Overflow. [This question on Unity Answers](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/colliders-of-complex-shape.133776/) comes to mind.

Comment: I tried using a convex mesh collider on the character, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @user379468 Is 'isTrigger' maybe ticked? That way the collider doesn't stop objects. If you disable 'isTrigger', it should block objects.

Comment: It is also important to note, that it isn't enough to put a collider on an object, and it automatically collides correctly with everything in the scene. You need to define a new layer, and every object in this layer is used against collision detections with given colliders.

Comment: What may be helpful to readers of the question is if you shared screenshots of the properties for each object. That would narrow down the possible reasons significantly.